# Addition to nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I wanted to add element with the next value to the most nested list, i. e.

For list

```
list_in = [2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 6], 2, [5, 6]]
```

The program should return

```
list_out = [2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 6], 2, [5, 6]]
```

In case with e. x. two equal nests, I wanted to get:

```
list_in = [2, [4], [3]]

list_out = [2, [4, 5], [3, 4]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: So the important part, then, is how to *find* the "most nested" list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```py
list_in = [2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7], 6], 2, [5, 6]]


def get_depths(lst, depths, current_depth=0):
    out = [
        get_depths(v, depths, current_depth + 1) if isinstance(v, list) else v
        for v in lst
    ]
    depths.setdefault(current_depth, []).append(out)
    return out


depths = {}
list_out = get_depths(list_in, depths)
for lst in depths[max(depths)]:
    lst.append(lst[-1] + 1)

print(list_out)
```

Prints:

```py
[2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, 8], 6], 2, [5, 6]]
```

---

For `list_in = [2, [4], [3]]` it prints:

```py
[2, [4, 5], [3, 4]]
```